# Limit number of emails pulled from Inbox

Tags: c#, outlook

I'm utilize Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook and populating a collection. An inbox I'm currently dealing with has over 10k emails. Is there a way for me to limit the number of emails that is pulled OR narrow my search?

```
public void InitializeInbox()
{
    Outlook.Application app = new Outlook.Application();
    Outlook.NameSpace outlookNs = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
    inboxFolder = outlookNs.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
    outlookNs.SendAndReceive(true);
    foreach (object _obj in inboxFolder.Items)
    {
        if (_obj is Outlook.MailItem)
        {
            receivedEmail.Add((Outlook.MailItem) _obj);
        }
   }

    ConcurrentBag<EmailDTO> concurrentEmails = new ConcurrentBag<EmailDTO>();

    Parallel.ForEach(
        receivedEmail, mail =>
        {
            mail.ReplyAll();
            concurrentEmails.Add(
            new EmailDTO
            {
                Subject = mail.Subject,
                Sender  = mail.SenderName,
                Body    = mail.HTMLBody,
                Date    = mail.SentOn.Date
            });
        });

    Inbox = new BindableCollection<EmailDTO>(concurrentEmails.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date));
}
```

So instead of searching through inboxFolder.Items, I want to be able to set a limit. For example `inboxFolder.Items.Where(x => x.Date >= DateTime.Now.AddYear(-1)`)

I can limit by using Restrict, but I only came across restricting unread emails.

```
inbox.Items.Restrict("[Unread]=true");
```

I've figured out how to restrict by dates, now how do I limit the number of entries?

Restricting by date

```
inboxFolder.Items.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] > '" + DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm") + "'")
```

Explicit limit with a sort.

```
List<Outlook.MailItem> receivedEmail = new List<Outlook.MailItem>();
const int limit = 200;

Outlook._Items items = inboxFolder.Items.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] >= '" + DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm") + "'");
items.Sort("[ReceivedTime]");
object item = items.GetNext();
int i = 1;
do
{
    // not every item is a mail item
    if (item is Outlook.MailItem)
    {
        receivedEmail.Add((Outlook.MailItem)item);
    }


    item = items.GetNext();
    i++;
} while (null != item && i < limit);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use LINQ when working with OOM, use an explicit "for" loop if you don't have a restriction. Better yet, use [MAPIFolder.GetTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mapifolder.gettable).

What is the restriction that you are using? Is there a restriction? Why do you call ReolyAll?

Comment: Hi @Dmitry, I successfully was able to query top 200 emails within last year, but the order is not quite what I wanted it in. I rather it query inbox descending instead of ascending. Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: You must call Items.Sort first. Make sure you store the Items object in an explicit variable instead of using multiple dot notation (which gives you a brand new COM object each time).

Comment: hi @Dmitry, I updated the code. I'm not entirely sure where I'm going wrong. I set the sort. I can remove the receive time restriction if I can query top 200 most recent.

Comment: That look Ok to me, but I'd retrieve the original MAPIFolder.Items colleciton, sort it, then use Items.Find / FindNext instead of restrict.